# How to obtain the name of the disk given the disk ID?

Tags: bash, macos, filesystems, disk, stat

The `stat` system call (`man 2 stat`) returns the ID of the device containing the file.

In a script, this ID can be obtained with, say

```
perl -e 'print((stat "/tmp/blah.txt")[0])'
```

Given the ID, how do I obtain the name of the disk, such as `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/disk1s1`?

I want to do it in a script (bash, perl, etc.) preferably in a portable way so that it works reliably both on MacOS and Linux.

Comment: That's an interesting use of `warn`. Why not `print`? Shoot, why perl instead of [`stat(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html): `stat -c '%d' /tmp`

Comment: @Shawn portability maybe? does macos have stat?

Comment: @ogizismail Isn't stat a posix command? And I remember seeing something about how apple is removing scripting languages from the os...

Comment: @Shawn no it isn't, it comes with GNU coreutils. You can search standards [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). *removing scripting languages from the os* really?

Comment: @oguzismail - yes, it does have stat but the cmd-line options are completely different.

Comment: we can work that out, but first tell us if our answers are helpful or not

Comment: @oguzismail Really. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes#3318257

Comment: @oguzismail - I was hoping there was some less convoluted than working out the differences between different implementations of `stat`; another syscall maybe wrapped in some cmd-line utility or exposed in some python/perl module (same way `stat` is exposed either as the `/usr/bin/stat` program, `os.stat` in python on `stat` in perl.)

Comment: I don't think there is a single call for that. What `df file` on Linux does for finding filesystem name is: 1- it stats file 2- parses the device id using major/minor makedev macros 3- reads `/proc/self/mountinfo` 4- finds the line containing major:minor and extracts 10th field. Looks like a lot of work, and not portable

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'df' to enumerate the file system, and create a map between device IDs and disk. Recall the each df line will list the mount point (/dev/sda1, ...) in the first column, and the mount point on the 5th column).

The following script uses bash associative array for the map, and stat -c '%d' to extract the 'dev' value of a given path.

```
# Create map dev2fs
function file2dev {
   stat -c '%d' "$1"
# If needed, use Perl equivalent
#    perl -e 'print ((stat($ARGV[0]))[0])' "$1"
}

declare -A dev2fs
while read fs size used available use mount ; do
    id=$(file2dev $mount);
    [ "$id" ] &&  dev2fs[$id]=$fs
done <<< "$(df)"

# Map a file to device
dev=$(file2dev /path/to/file );
echo "Device=${dev2fs[$dev]}"
```

Also, possible to iterate over mounted file system using 'mount -l'. I'm not sure which one exists on MacOS.

Comment: I have learnt so much by reading this script - here strings, associate arrays, etc. None of it was available when I read the bash manual last time : )

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to re-invent the wheel.
Given a file name, the filesystem name it belongs to can be found in last row's first column in `df`'s output. E.g:

```
df -P /tmp | awk 'END { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Nice and simple but works only under Linux. Under BSD/MacOS `df ~/.bashrc` produces the same output as `df`.

Comment: well, it does work with `-P`. (Even though the man page says it's supposed to do something else: _Use (the default) 512-byte blocks.  This is only useful as a way to override an BLOCKSIZE specification from the environment_.)

Comment: What I gather form the spec is -P is for generating a portable output, although neither Linux nor BSD man pages speak to that

Comment: Good think to know about -P, +1